# Ford Escape, 2009 base model, foot heat

Tags: ford, escape, heater-control

We have very low flow to the foot area on our Escape.  Air from the upper, side and defrost vents seems to be fine.  When 'foot' is selected, we get some air out of the dash and side vents but definitely less than when they are selected (same fan speed).  Somewhere there's a selector door not opening but where is it?  I hear no clicking sounds like a motor cycling.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Don't know about your car specifically, but it's going to be buried behind the dash, and these flaps often use vacuum power to open and close so you may hear a slight hiss rather than an electric hum or click.

Comment: You could try cycling through all the settings may "free up" the sticking flap - it's one of the suggestions made for other cars..

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Just checking on a parts site, I think this has motors for all of the flappers: blend; air inlet; foot door; defrost door. Oh, the tangled web we weave. Four Seasons has PN: 73035 for this part. Standard Motor Products has it under PN: J04025.